# Background-image url in php echo

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-image

So I am using `bootstrap css` with my PHP website. For some reason I can get an `img src` to print just fine using the same location. But when i need to use background-image the images do not show. I cannot figure out why. Here is the section I am trying to get to show the standard bootstrap code.

```
//<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      echo '<div class="carousel-inner">';
      echo '<div class="item active">';
      echo '<div class="fill" style="background-image:url("http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One");"></div>';
      echo '<div class="carousel-caption">';
      echo '<h2>Caption 1</h2>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '<div class="item">';
      echo '<div class="fill" style="background-image:url("http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Two");"></div>';
      echo '<div class="carousel-caption">';
      echo '<h2>Caption 2</h2>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '<div class="item">';
      echo '<div class="fill" style="background-image:url("http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide Three");"></div>';
      echo '<div class="carousel-caption">';
      echo '<h2>Caption 3</h2>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '</div>';
```

The fill css is this:

```
header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

When I put it in a normal `html` file it works fine. However, I am using `php` and autoloading, hence the need to use echo statements to print out the html parts. I don't know why this is not displaying the images. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are conflicting.

Try `echo '<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(\'http://placehold.it/1900x1080&text=Slide One\');"></div>';`

Answer (score 0):

CSS looks ok, must be a CORS issue. Assuming you're using https on your site, your urls need to be https too. Or you could just remove the protocol and let the urls start with "//", then it automatically load on whichever protocol your page is loaded.

Also, use heredocs, that stack of echos is nasty.

```
echo <<<HTM
your
html
goes here
HTM;
```